# What is the original superlative form of well?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I know that “well” (as in the adverb “to do well”) has a superlative form, “best,” but this is suppletive, and I’ve always wanted to know what the original, as in, the last, not suppletive, superlative form of “well” (same usage as before) was, since “best” just doesn’t sound right, and it’s the superlative form of “good” as well, so saying “best” could mean two completely different things.

Comment: I'm not sure about a differing 'original' (though if you are, then [etymology] tag might suit), but in many contexts "most" can serve as generic superlative as an adverb (context  in part dictating its intended position on goodness-badness spectrum), either supplementing in front of or replacing 'well'.

Comment: If referring to "well" the adjective as in good health, then depending on context you could say "I'm all the way recovered." or "I'm much more well." though stilted. The option of switching to the generic -better-best while less than ideal can convey the full meaning when taken in well-construted context.

Comment: Well: The adjective was in Old English in the sense "in good fortune, happy," from the adverb; sense of "satisfactory" is from late 14c.; "agreeable to wish or desire" is from mid-15c.; "in good health, not ailing" is from 1550s.

Comment: Good, better, best. Where does *well* come in here?

Comment: Do you mean "well" in the sense of "that was done well" or "a well-done steak" rather than referring to someone's health. The definition of "well" can be thought of as very flexible, so flexible in fact that I'm not too sure that a universal superlative form of "well" can actually be found (although there is a very weak case for "I'll have the wellest done steak")

Comment: The question has no context: it is too broad.

Comment: I mean well as in good health: “I am feeling well”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a comparative form of "well"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/is-there-a-comparative-form-of-well)

Comment: You should unaccept the answer, for a bit I thought "maybe" but I checked and there is nothing out there that supports its conclusion i.e. that *the original superlative of "well" was "wellest" with origins dating back to early 19th century*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

‘wellest’ was a non-Standard usage with origins dating back to early 19th century:

> ...*In other cases, I have chosen the **wellest** time and never omit it when pain or sickness attend the rise of a fever.*
>
> — [Bulletin of the Lloyd Library of Botany, Pharmacy and Materia Medica](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vicJAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA56&dq=%22wellest%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYiNm04N7yAhUP4YUKHZEIDRUQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=Wellest&f=false), 1812

[image]

---

Update: Since someone pointed out n-gram was inaccurate. I will refer to OED for this, which says that the form was non-Standard, but it did exist and fallen out of usage like the n-gram suggests. Note, this is taken from the OED’s dictionary entry on “well”.

[image]

Comment: That you found an example were "wellest" is used, is not substantive evidence. As they say, one swallow does not make a spring. I have searched a bit on my own, and did not find any 19th century grammars that listed it, quite the contrary but I shall continue to hunt, before casting a downvote.

Comment: This seems like "wellest time" is being used to mean "when the patient is feeling most well" not "best time".

Comment: *“A procession of eight persons – one, a man on horseback riding single the others men and women partly riding double, partly on foot in the muddiest highway **in the wellest weather;** singing, all but the single rider, at whose bridle walk and splash two women: Hosannah! Holy holy! Lord God of Sabaoth” and other things “in a buzzing tone” which the impartial hearer could not make out.* 1846, The United States Democratic Review

Comment: And that's about it, I found many instances of the German *wellest*, and pieces of 19th century literature that had false positives such as  *dwellest* and *swellest*

Comment: Ack, just realised the [example above](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_United_States_Democratic_Review/BjE4AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=in+the+muddiest+highway+in+the+wellest&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover) is a mistranscription for "wettest". It's a -1 because I found no valid examples on Google books for "the wellest".

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're right that this answer is ᴡᴀʏ wrong. It's ridiculous to pretend anything original happened to English more than a thousand years into its history during the 19th century. It was never more than a nonstandard blunder. Although *best* is of course the suppletive superlative for both *good* and *well*, and has been for a very, **very** long time now, there used to be another coëxtant version, which you can find in both the Old English of *Beowulf* and the Middle English of *Brut*. We just don’t use it any longer in Modern English. (NB: Adjectives and adverbs were once the same.)

Comment: @tchrist Language is dictated by non-standard ‘blunder’ and so are all the other archaic forms good/gooder/goodest. Second, language is relative. It would have been grammatical during that period and not in modern English. Which is why I said “The original superlative ... **was** ...”. The ngrams support that it was highly in use in the 18th century, not just a mere blunder.

Comment: If the word never existed, why is it in the dictionaries: https://www.yourdictionary.com/wellest, https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wellest ?

Comment: Ngram for [**the wellest**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20wellest%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1846&lr=lang_en) All of the results are printing errors. All. I spent a long time looking for 19th century examples and came up empty handed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're still utterly wrong. "Original" doesn't mean in the 19th Century. If it ain't before the 9th Century, 'tain't an original. You're a thousand years too late. Also, you seem to be miscounting your centuries again. Go back and look at the 9th century for the right answer. This is currently the wrong answer.

Comment: An NGram of a single word only shows that the spelling may have occurred. It doesn't give meaning at all (unless you search for multiple words around it to give some context), and it is very difficult to read off general recognizability from the y-scale (especially if you cut it off). Also you would want to give the NGram link (not just a screen shot) so that people can more easily confirm. You may want to get some relative frequency also in your NGram, by comparing it with other words (like 'best').

Comment: One more thing... anybody can put things into Wiktionary (and they seem to do so) and so I find it a bit untrustworthy. I don't know enough about YourDictionary to make a similar judgement. There is a trend, which I admire, to have a repository of all 'word-like' things (ie not a list of 'this is definitely a word' words). But that trend needs to be open and not put every word at the same level of acceptance. "used since 900 AD every other sentence" is not the same as "kids say it a few times then learn the exception" is not the same as "I just made it up because I wanted to".

Comment: @tchrist Also tchrist, the definition of “original” is already murky at best. “If it is not before the 9th century, it is not original”. Where is your proof on this? This is merely opinionated. Furthermore where is your evidence that the “superlative for both good and well, is **best** and has been for a very, very long time now, there used to be another coëxtant version, which you can find in both the Old English of Beowulf and the Middle English of Brut.” Where did you even find that *best* and *well* were even etymologically related? Again opinion-based and beyond the scope of this website.

Answer (score 9):

Since 'well' is a [suppletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) of 'good', I'll just treat 'good' and 'well' together.

What is the original superlative (and comparative) of 'good'? The current Late Modern English pattern is 'good' -> 'better' -> 'best'. The regular rule of English would suppose it is the childish-sounding over-regularized 'good' -> 'gooder' -> 'goodest'. So the question is asking what were 'better' and 'best' before? What is it that they replaced? What was the original regularity? 'good' -> 'X-er' -> 'X-est' or 'Y' -> 'Y-er' -> 'Y-est'?

Sometimes the original pattern shows up in other nearby languages. In all the related Germanic languages, Dutch, German (both West Germanic), and the North German (Danish, Norwegian, Icelandic), **they -all- have the same cognate series**, like [good, better best but with appropriate sound changes for each branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion#Good_and_bad). Swedish just -has- to be different having replaced 'gut' with 'bra' from Italian bravo' in the 17th c.

This means that all the Germanic languages have the same question, what corresponds to 'good' in the comparative/superlative? If you try to go further back, to Proto-Indo-European, none of the other branches share a cognate with 'good' or 'better' - all have roots entirely different from Proto-Germanic (e.g. Proto-Italic bonum, melior, optimum; Proto-Slavic dobro, lepshi/bolji - .

So there doesn't seem to be any word that was replaced. Except there is some slight evidence that 'good' itself was the lexical item that was replaced, not the less frequent comparative/superlative.

There is a Proto-Germanic word 'bat' meaning advantage or improvement.  Its [comparative form was 'batizon' and its superlative was 'batistaz'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/better) which is uncontroversially the the etymon of 'better' and 'best'. **The simple adjective 'bat' was replaced by 'good'.** In other words, while it is commonly understood that the 'bet-' root suppleted some derivation of 'good', it seems more likely rather that 'good' suppleted the regular paradigm entry of 'bat'.

The table for the this is in Wikipedia's article on suppletion - the [paradigms of good better best](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion#Good_and_bad). There they give examples of 'good' in all the European families.

In many Germanic languages, it turns out that there may be a possible remnant of 'bat'. In English, it is surmised that the word 'boot' as in [etymonline, n 2](https://www.etymonline.com/word/boot)

> I got a dozen bagels and the baker put in another one **to boot**.

The answer to the title question is that **there really is no *original* comparative/superlative that is known**, but that there is more likely an original (ie older) version of 'good' that makes the paradigm regular, and that word is cognate with 'to boot' meaning 'extra'.

---

@tchrist pointed out to me that in Old English and surviving into Middle English (and in other Germanics), there was an alternative synonymous paradigm based on 'sel-'.

Comment: Best is not the superlative of *good*. If you replaced wellest with good in the following sentence: I had the wellest time / I had the * good time, it would be grammatically incorrect. Only *best* would be logical there. Therefore in modern English the **superlative** for *well* is best (replacing wellest, not good). Also does this really answer the question? It seems to be a stretch and never to the point.

Comment: @aesking You seem to have misread all of this completely, considering that contrary to your assertion, *best* most definitely  and very much ***is*** the superlative of the adjective *good* (while also being the superlative of the adverb *well*)! Swapping in *good* for a superlative in *❌ I had the good time* breaks because you've chosen the positive degree, which brooks no definite article, rather than the superlative degree.

Comment: Mitch, while your answer is certainly interesting, it doesn’t have anything to do with my question.

Comment: @Ami Can you clarify then? Is it that I talk about 'good' instead of 'well'?

Comment: @aesking false positives, instances of "wellest" are mostly OCR errors, the ones I found were: swellest, dwellest, and wettest. Then there were instances found in German literature. Check the results. Always.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then why is the word in dictionaries: https://www.yourdictionary.com/wellest, https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/wellest ?

Comment: @aesking because people are always inventing workarounds, it makes "sense" that the comparative of *well* should be *weller* and the superlative *wellest*, but it's not standard English as we know it.  In fact, many native speakers say "badder" and "baddest" but a pedant or a grammarian will roll their eyes.

Comment: @aesking  No native speaker would be making these mistakes you're making here. Maybe check [ell.se].

Comment: Yes, I asked a question about the forms of “well” but you were talking about “good” so while what you said was intriguing, it wasn’t answering my question.

Comment: @Ami Words have multiple meanings. 'well' is usually considered an adverbial form of 'good', but it can have other meanings. You should specify which meaning you are interested in by editing your post above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: there wasn't one. The OED says:

> Like that of **good** *adj.*, the Germanic base of **well** *adv.* appears to have had no regular comparative or superlative, these forms being supplied by formations from the common base of **better** *adv.* and **best** *adv.*

So the superlative of *well* going back to Old English was **best**.

The use of *well* as an adjective comes from *well* as an adverb back in Old English, and there is often uncertainty which is being used. So we can take them as having the same origin and same comparative and superlative.

- "well, adv. and n.4". OED Online. March 2023. Oxford University Press. (accessed March 27, 2023).
- "well, adj. and n.3". OED Online. March 2023. Oxford University Press.  (accessed March 27, 2023).

Answer (score 0):

I'm more inclined to agree with Stuart F's answer here:

> The answer is: there wasn't one

But I do not agree to this:

> So the superlative of well going back to Old English was best.

In fact they are quite contradictory. I prefer '*Best* was the superlative used for *well* in-lieu of non-existent regular forms in Old English.' Otherwise some may errenously mistake well/good as having an etymologically connection with best.
Interesting fact:

> Old English beste, reduced by assimilation of -t- from earlier Old English betst "of the highest quality or standing, first, in the best manner." **This originally was the superlative of bōt "remedy, reparation"** (Middle English bote "advantage, help, profit"), a word now surviving in its simple form only in the expression to boot (see boot (n.2)). Its comparative, *better*, and superlative, *best*, have been **transferred** to good (and in some cases, ***well***).
>
> Old English bōt is from Proto-Germanic root *bat-, with comparative *batizon and superlative *batistaz.
>
> Source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/best

In Old English, ['regular' superlatives](https://oldenglish.info/adj4.html#:%7E:text=The%20superlative%20is%20made%20by,the%20highest%20and%20holiest%20god%27.&text=While%20comparative%20adjectives%20always%20decline,or%20strong%20depending%20on%20context.) were made by the suffix -st or -ost. There are very few irregular adjectives such as good, well and bad. If they were to follow the regular morphology, then they would be as follows:

Good -> gooder -> goodest 
Well -> weller -> wellest 
Bad -> badder -> baddest

It seems this conundrum is not a new issue conjured to present day, but rather a confusion caused from the irregularity of their declensions and even today, depending on your vernacular, some of these declensions are considered more acceptable than others e.g. 'goodest' and 'baddest'. For example, Colin's dictionary considers baddest as an entry in British vernacular.

Though, it is **indisputable** that the Standard forms used in **lieu of their non existent regular comparative and superlative forms** are below:

Good -> better-> best 
Well -> better -> best 
Bad -> *worser/more worse -> worst 
Worse -> *worser/more worse -> worst

---

<sup>*These may be considered *archaic* or non-Standard. Worser is taken from Shakespearean English: https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/worser/. But in daily conversation, I have heard of the usage 'worser'. Avoid in essay writing.</sup>